# Reaction while holding a readied action?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, readied-action, reactions

So when you hold an action using the Ready action you use your reaction to act when the trigger happens. however you're able to ignore the trigger. So while you are using the Ready action, are you able to take a DIFFERENT reaction before the trigger (or after if you ignored it) at the cost of losing the readied action?

Scenario: Fighter is fighting a bird and a goblin. The goblin is in melee range. The fighter readies a sword attack for when the bird comes into range. The goblin acts before the bird and leaves the fighter's range. Can the Fighter take an attack of opportunity - expending his reaction, and thus unreadying the attack on the bird?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  Good question, it never occurred to me to wonder this.  Check out the [tour] when you have the time, and enjoy your time here!

Comment: This question and the duplicate relationship of two other linked questions (the one it's currently closed as a dupe of, and the other linked one) are being discussed in [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9610/should-something-be-done-about-the-current-duplicate-statuses-of-these-related-q).